# Kernel option in /sys change

Tags: proc

If /proc/sys and /sys are the same, can I change the kernel options in /sys not in /proc/sys?

If not, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are not the same: `/proc/sys` gives access to [`sysctl` files](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/sysctl/), which provide various configuration options for kernel features; `sys` is [`sysfs`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/sysfs.5.html), which gives access to kernel data structures.

Some of these might overlap, so a setting in `/proc/sys` could show up in the corresponding data structure in `/sys`. In such cases you can’t change one without changing the other.